# CSS multi border

Tags: css

I don't know why this doesn't show a extra border can you see what I'm doing wrong?

```
.loginSubmit {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #e0e0e0;
    border: 1px solid #dedede;
    color: #555555;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: white 0px 1px;

    /* firefox */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eaeaea, #f0f0f0 100%);
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;

    /* webkit */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#eaeaea), to(#f0f0f0));
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
}

.loginSubmit:before {
    width: 98px;
    height: 98px;
    content '';
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot a colon in the `.loginSubmit:before` statement, which will make the rule invalid. So it won't render.

Make it like this:

```
.loginSubmit:before {
    width: 98px;
    height: 98px;
    content: ''; /* <-- extra colon here */
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

This example is working in firefox:
http://jsfiddle.net/bxTv7/

**Update:**
Check this question: [Can I use the :after pseudo-element on an input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/css-after-pseudo-element-on-input-field)

Comment: @Mamix i cant get it to work :/ is it because its a submit button i use?

Comment: @ole: `<input class="loginSubmit" type="submit"/>` doesn't seem to work indeed. Does the `input`-tag have a pseudoclass for before? Did you check if that works at all?

Comment: @Mamix hm i dont know what you mean about pseudoclass have before, do you mean if the submit dont have the pseudoclass "before"?

Comment: @ole. I mean: does `input:before` work? Does it exist? Is it specified in the HTML specifications of the w3? Or is it unsupported by all browsers?

Comment: its supported i have seen alot of people use it and says you can use it to make multi border, (but only see the multi effect on divs)

Comment: @ole: Check the question in the update. It tells you that it can only be done with containers.

Comment: @Mamix that sux :( i found out i can use outline: 1px solid #333; but i use border-radius and outline dont take effect on that so :/ nothing i can do :(

Comment: @ole: Is it really that you just want an extra border around your button or do you want something else? Why not put the button inside a div with a border?

Comment: @ole: or the other way around?